# Linq Dynamic Group By

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic, group-by

Hi i need dynamic linq queries which has group by in vb.net.

My queries are as following.

In first query i need to group by two columns, but in second i need to group by just one column. It depens on how user wants to see the report.

How can i produce these queries on runtime according to the user choices?

Thanks in advance.

```
Dim query = From r In dtString.AsEnumerable
        Group r By Key0 = r.Field(Of String)("country"),
                   Key1 = r.Field(Of String)("region") Into Group
        Select Key0, Key1,
               DebitTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("debit")),
               CreditTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("credit"))


Dim query = From r In dtString.AsEnumerable
        Group r By Key0 = r.Field(Of String)("country") Into Group
        Select Key0
               DebitTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("debit")),
               CreditTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("credit"))
```

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you use `If..Else`?

Comment: i used select case. But key field count changes according to user choices and it can be 1 or 7. So i had to recode same thing 7 times. And this won't be dynamic if one day report key field count raises to 100 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your `Select` clauses, the result of your two queries are not (anonymous) type compatible. Your simplest solution may be to alter your second query to something that does have a second redundant or constant group key.

E.g.

```
query = From r In dtString.AsEnumerable
    Group r By Key0 = r.Field(Of String)("country"),
               Key1 = r.Field(Of String)("country") Into Group
    Select Key0, Key1,
           DebitTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("debit")),
           CreditTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("credit"))
```

or

```
query = From r In dtString.AsEnumerable
    Group r By Key0 = r.Field(Of String)("country"),
               Key1 = "ignored" Into Group
    Select Key0, Key1,
           DebitTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("debit")),
           CreditTotal = Group.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("credit"))
```

(untested)

Then you'll have to adjust your result display to ignore `key1` when required.

Comment: Thanks, i guess the most effective solution is your first example.